Trouble finding frame hanger Daymak to Shimano RD-R3000
Having a really tough time finding the following part:
Frame hanger
3/4inch 1.9mm width screw holes.
Frame # DMK17PR000000004
Derailer # RD-R3000
I've ordered a few, but there is always something slightly off, such as the screw hole width or the indent curve.

Hi, welcome to bicycles.  This question could be improved with some pictures showing the parts in question.
